# Listen on TCP and UDP on the same port

Tags: haskell, tcp, network-programming, udp

How can I get Haskell to listen for UDP and TCP on the same port?

Here is the code I have so far (based on acme-http):

```
listenOn portm = do                                                             
  protoTCP <- getProtocolNumber "tcp"                                         
  E.bracketOnError                                                            
    (socket AF_INET Stream protoTCP)                                        
    sClose                                                                  
    (\sock -> do                                                            
        setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1                                    
        setSocketOption sock NoDelay 1                                      
        bindSocket sock (SockAddrInet (fromIntegral portm) iNADDR_ANY)        
        listen sock (max 1024 maxListenQueue)                               
        return sock                                                         
    )                                                                       
  protoUDP <- getProtocolNumber "udp"                                         
  E.bracketOnError                                                            
    (socket AF_INET Datagram protoUDP)                                      
    sClose                                                                  
    (\sock -> do                                                            
        setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1                                    
        bindSocket sock (SockAddrInet (fromIntegral portm) iNADDR_ANY)        
        return sock                                                         
    )
```

I compiles fine, but I get the follow runtime error:

```
user error (accept: can't perform accept on socket ((AF_INET,Datagram,17)) in status Bound)
```

Unfortunately, documentation on network programming in Haskell is a bit limited (as usual). I don't really know where I'm supposed to look to figure this stuff out.

**[UPDATE]**
For anyone is interested, here is the result:

https://github.com/joehillen/acme-sip/blob/master/Acme/Serve.hs

I realize there is a lot of room for improvement, but it works.

Comment: Specifics of your setup would be helpful.  Your code works fine for me on GHC 7.6.3 x86-64, Linux, using network 2.4.1.2.  Also, the jab on documentation is unnecessary - Network is moderately well documented, is largely direct C calls so the man pages are useful, and the package is on github so you can feel free to send patches.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code, but somewhere else your code seems to be calling `accept()` on the UDP socket, which isn't legal. All you need to do with a UDP socket is receive from it and send with it.